# DOMDocument::loadHtml with not encoded "<" char inside

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I need to load some html code with not encoded "<" char:

```
<p> some text < 5  </p>
```

```php
$someHTML = '<p> some text < 5  </p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $someHTML);
```

And inside my object I'm getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"??>
    <p> </p>
```

istead of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"??>
    <p> some text < 5  </p>
```

Any idea how to load HTML with "<" inside tags? I know it should be encoded to `&lt;` but I have only clean version of that. And I can't easly encode only "<" chars without breaking real HTML tags.

Real HTML I'm working with is huge and very complicated.

Comment: Why not run a script through the html to find and change the special characters within the tags

Comment: @MatthewKerian and  how would you do that without replacing tag and without parsing html?

Comment: You'd have to parse HTML

Comment: @MatthewKerian and that's a problem I've described...  I can't parse it because of the '<' inside. It's not parsing correctly.

Comment: I don't mean parse it normally. I mean you'd have to go through and parse the HTML to find the mistakes then get rid of them. There may be another way to do it or a lib that'll do it for you but not that I can think of

Comment: But it's not a mistake. It's just a valid "<" char in the description. I think `loadHTML` has some bug and can't parse it ;)

Comment: I mean get rid of the mistake, not get rid of the char